# Level Curves of a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Can someone explain how to solve questions like these?

Prove that the level curves of the plane ax+by+cz=d are parallel lines in the xy-plane, provided a2+b2≠0 and c≠0.

Comment: What do you mean by “level curves of the plane?” Do you mean the level curves of the function $f(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz-d$?

Comment: I believe that is what the textbook question is referring to. The answer was all lines have slope - a/b but I am confused as to why?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like you’re meant to take $ax+by+cz=d$ as implicitly defining a function of $x$ and $y$. Hint: What does the equation look like if you plug in a specific value for $z$?

Answer (score 0):

The family of planes $ax+by+cz=d$ define, implicitly, a family of functions $z = f(x,y) = \frac{1}{c}[d-ax-by]$, for $c \neq 0$. To find the level curves of this function, you fix $z=k$ for an arbitrary constant $k$. This leads to: \begin{eqnarray}
ck = d-ax-by \tag{1} \label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
Because $ck$ and $d$ are constants, we can write $ck-d = \alpha$, and (\ref{1}) becomes:
\begin{eqnarray}
\alpha = -ax-by \tag{2} \label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
These is a family of lines with slopes $-a/b$, once we can rewrite (\ref{2}) as:
\begin{eqnarray}
y = -\frac{a}{b}x -\frac{\alpha}{b} 
\end{eqnarray}